# Como encender xampp en conjunto con un programa de escritorio?

Tags: xampp, netbeans-8.2

mi pregunta es la siguiente ,estoy aprendiendo a programar y recientemente cree un pequeño programa de escritorio en netbeans y me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de que cada vez que abra el programa de tipo jar me inicie también la base de datos que tengo en xampp para que pueda guardar y obtener información, para que la persona que va a usar el programa no tenga que activar la base de datos antes de usar el programa sino que se le abra y cierre automáticamente con  el programa, o alguna solución alternativa que me puedan informar? desde ya muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programa en Java, ¿verdad?

Desde una aplicación Java se pueden arrancar programas del equipo, usando la clase ***Runtime***, por ejemplo:

```
try 
{ 
   /* directorio/ejecutable es el path del ejecutable y un nombre */ 
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec ("directorio/ejecutable"); 
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{ 
   /* Se lanza una excepción si no se encuentra en ejecutable o el fichero no es ejecutable. */ 
}
```

Código de: http://www.chuidiang.org/java/ejemplos/Runtime/runtime.php

Y si consigues abrir *Xampp* desde tu programa, deberás tenerlo configurado para que arranque automáticamente los servicios que requieras (en el propio Xampp).